# Как защитить google chrome расширение?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

т.к. google chrome расширения пишутся на javascript, который является некомпилируемым языком программирования, то любой желающий может выдернуть исходный код и использовать его в своем расширении или, например, выложить его в общий доступ (если приложение является платным). Собственно это и является проблемой. Как защитить google chrome расширение?

Answer (score 4):

Нормально защитить невозможно. Можно попробовать создать трудности при копировании, но не более того. Расширения и приложения работают на машине клиента, а значит исходники и контент могут быть скопированы.

В данном случае вопрос копирования и использования Вашего JS "любым желающим" скорее из области права, чем программирования.